# array conversion in php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

how would you convert this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Contact] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 0425 234 634
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Contact] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 2939 492 235
                )

        )

)
```

into this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0425 234 634
    [1] => 2939 492 235
)
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very dirty method, don't think there is a function to do this for you though.

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array2[$key]=$value['contact']['number'];
}
```

EDIT:

Actually, [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) might be of some help, would be worth testing it against your multi-dimensional array.

Comment: values in the mentioned array are in fact arrays themselves thus turning array_values useless in the current context. try it!

Comment: It may well be, didn't get chance to test it with a multi-dimensional array :-)

Comment: thank you, i tried array_values() there are some interesting ways to flatten arrays in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php 
ill try your solution too, if it works you get a tick ;)

Comment: you can use array_shift to flatten your array. Check out my answer below

Comment: Use CakePHP's Set::extract function (similar to Set::classicExtract() below) - do this in 1 line of code not 3, and it's far more readable.

Answer (score 7):

See [Set::extract()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/671/extract) It uses xpath notation to extract node values from paths in arrays.

$numbers = Set::extract('/Contact/number', $numbers);

Achieve all this in 1 line in far more understandable code than other examples suggested here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning current usage of Set::extract (xpath as opposed to dot notation)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using CakePHP, there is an included [utility library](http://book.cakephp.org/view/669/classicExtract) that does just what you need.

```
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        'Contact' => array(
                'number' => "0425 234 634"
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Contact' => array(
                'number' => "2939 492 235"
        )
    )
);

$b = Set::classicExtract($a, '{n}.Contact.number');

print_r($b);
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0425 234 634
    [1] => 2939 492 235
)
```

Comment: Why not the modern `Set::extract('/Contact/number', $a)`?

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen solutions using a seperate array to store the results, this would work just as fine:

```
<?php
    foreach($numbers as $key => $number) {
        $numbers[$key] = $number['Contact']['number'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, fully functional and without any assumptions about your original array :)

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'number' => 123123123
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'number' => 123123123
        )
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'number' => 123123123
        )
    ),
);


function flattenArray(array $arr, &$newArr) {
    while($array = array_shift($arr)) {
        if(is_array($array)) {
            flattenArray($array, $newArr);
        } else {
            $newArr[] = $array;
        }
    }
}

$newArr = array();

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    flattenArray($value, $newArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class DeepCollect {
  protected $arr = array();

  public function collect($item, $key) {
    $this->arr[] = $item;
  }

  public static function collect_all($array) {
    $collect = new self;
    array_walk_recursive($array, array($collect, "collect"));
    return $collect->arr;
  }
}

print_r(DeepCollect::collect_all($input_array));
```

Will work for any nested-array irrespective of key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This should work also with

```
Set:extract( "{n}.Contact.number", $a );
Set::extract( "/number", $a );
```